# For-loop within a function

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, loops, for-loop

I am currently taking a short course on python and am having a bit of trouble with an assignment.

The task is to create a function that takes a list of names and marks e.g. [Student 1, 35, Student 2, 78] etc as an argument and outputs a grade based on a marking scheme.

I have working code but i feel like its not quite satisfying the question. I have defined a function that determines the grade and then use a for-loop to call that function and apply it to every item in a list. I feel like there is a more elegant solution where the function is doing the loop but am struggling to get it to work. I believe its something to do with the variables in the function being local and not global.

```
data = ["Fozzie", 34, "Kermit", 78, "Miss Piggy", 23, "Gonzo", 55, "Beaker", 88, "Honeydew", 59, "Animal", 10, "Rowlf", 54]

def assign_grades(source):
    student_name = str(source[student])
    mark = int(source[student + 1])
    grade = str("")
  
        
    if mark < 40:
        grade = "Fail"
    elif mark < 60:
        grade = "Pass"
    elif mark < 70:
        grade = "Merit"
    elif mark >= 70:
        grade = "Distinction"
    else:
        grade = "Error"


    return("---------------------------------------------"
          +"\nStudent Name: "
          +str(student_name)
          + "\nMark: "
          + str(mark)
          + "\nGrade: " + str(grade)
          +"\n---------------------------------------------")


for student in range(0, len(data), 2):
    print(assign_grades(data))
```

Comment: Mark:  -37465 should probably go to Error... but will be Fail

Comment: we dont see how data looks like, no idea if your code does what it should

Comment: Try passing in the arguments instead of using globals, the function should return results, not modify them.  Also pre-process the list to get (name, mark) instead of alternating types in the list, which is error-prone

Comment: Thank you for you speedy responses, i have edited the code to include a small set of the data. I have only been studying python for a couple of weeks so am very new at this. I don't think the function is modifying anything apart form appending results 
 to the to a new list, i have removed this now for clarity

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is cleaner or just more cryptic, but it uses less code and no global variables.

```
def get_marks():
    # get marks from database or user input
    # for testing, just return list
    mks = [("Fozzie", 34), ("Kermit", 78), ("Miss Piggy", 23), ("Gonzo", 55), ("Beaker", 88), ("Honeydew", 59), ("Animal", 10), ("Rowlf", 54)]
    return mks

def assign_grade(mark): # convert mark to grade
    lmts = [(40,'Fail'),(60,'Pass'),(70,'Merit'),(200,'Distinction')] # mark never over 200
    return [x[1] for x in lmts if x[0] >= mark][0]  # return first matching range

marks = get_marks()  # get name/mark data
grades = [assign_grade(m[1]) for m in marks] # pass/fail/...

for g in zip(marks,grades):  # merge name/mark/grade
    print ("---------------------------------------------"
       +"\nStudent Name: "
       +str(g[0][0])
       + "\nMark: "
       + str(g[0][1])
       + "\nGrade: " + str(g[1])
       +"\n---------------------------------------------")
```

Output

```
---------------------------------------------
Student Name: Fozzie
Mark: 34
Grade: Fail
---------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------
Student Name: Kermit
Mark: 78
Grade: Distinction
---------------------------------------------
.......
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i like the idea of using the list to define a set of criteria, I hadn't considered that it could be done that way. The main issue i had with the version i wrote was that there was no loop within the function ans to me this seemed to be cheating as the question asked to specifically to write a function that takes a list as an argument. I think i may be over complicating the matter.